# ng-Repeat rendering json in Order

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an json object like this Object: {V: Object, I: Object}, but at the time the ng-repeat is rendering and also when I'm expanding the watch on Chrome the json object looks like this:
[image: console image]

and in fact the rendering insise de ng-repeat happens in "alpha" order instead of the order that I give that is Object: {V: Object, I: Object}.

What can I do for the ng-repeat respect the order of the objects inside the json that I give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your version of Angular. This is an old behavior.

Comment: If you can, debug where the JSON gets retrieved from and see the order it's coming in. From what you've described, it sounds like that's the order the JSON is being received in.

Comment: Mike above in the image is how the json object is received before going to the ng-repeat, is weird that in the console also when I expand it appears in alpha order

Comment: I wondered if you didn't refresh or the update failed or something. :)